# Debian 12 bridged interface with static IPv4 and SLAAC IPv6 looses IPv4 connectivity

Tags: debian, ipv6, bridge, proxmox

My Debian 12 computer has a static IPv4 address 192.168.1.3/23, gateway is 192.168.1.1. Computer gets IPv6 address via SLAAC.

In order to use Proxmox, I have defined the /etc/network/interfaces -file as follows:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet6 auto
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.3/23
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    bridge-ports eno1
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

For Proxmox purposes, this works fine - virtual computers get their IPv4 from local gateway and IPv6 from operator via SLAAC. But this main computer works only with IPv6.

When I started debugging this, I noticed that first, `avahi-daemon` joins mDNS multicast group with IP 169.254.153.191 and then `connmand` changes IPv4 address to this same. After this, IPv4 connectivity was lost. Here is snippet from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
2023-06-24T23:36:40.625360+03:00 cathouse avahi-daemon[622]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 169.254.153.191.
2023-06-24T23:36:40.625549+03:00 cathouse avahi-daemon[622]: New relevant interface eno1.IPv4 for mDNS.
2023-06-24T23:36:40.625584+03:00 cathouse avahi-daemon[622]: Registering new address record for 169.254.153.191 on eno1.IPv4.
2023-06-24T23:36:40.641482+03:00 cathouse connmand[659]: eno1 {add} address 169.254.153.191/16 label eno1 family 2
2023-06-24T23:36:40.641562+03:00 cathouse connmand[659]: eno1 {add} route 169.254.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
2023-06-24T23:36:40.641595+03:00 cathouse connmand[659]: eno1 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
2023-06-24T23:36:40.641622+03:00 cathouse connmand[659]: eno1 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
```

The first step was to disable `connmand` on eno1 interface by adding following line to `/etc/connman/main.conf`:

```
# NetworkInterfaceBlacklist = vmnet,vboxnet,virbr,ifb,ve-,vb-
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist = eno,vmbr
```

This worked fine otherwise, but in boot, `connman-wait-online.service` kept on waiting for network to come online. The next step was `sudo systemctl disable connman-wait-online.service`, which helped on boot.

After this, the system worked fine: computer had both IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity and the `connmand` did not any more try to disable the IPv4.

But, after I created some Proxmox virtual machines and started them, tapXXXX network adapters appeared and `connmand` started to play again: it added default routes for them. Now the route table is as follows and IPv4 routing does not work any more. IPv6 works fine.

```
kalle@cathouse:/etc/network$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap201i0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 fwln102i0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap102i0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 fwpr102p0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap103i0
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 tap201i0
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 tap103i0
default         OpenWrt.home    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tap103i0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 fwpr102p0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tap102i0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 fwln102i0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tap201i0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
```

These were corrected by editing `/etc/connman/main.conf` to cover also tap* and fw* adapters:

```
# NetworkInterfaceBlacklist = vmnet,vboxnet,virbr,ifb,ve-,vb-
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist = eno,vmbr,fw,tap
```

So, to the question: how should I fix things in order to get both IPv4 and IPv6 working without goofing too much around with `connmand` configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

I think your address should be

```
address 192.168.1.3/24
```

Comment: No, it is /23 as it covers both 192.168.0.x and 192.168.1.x addresses.

Comment: Your config looks fine, no idea why your IPv4 is not working.